# Facebook fixed header without margin or padding bottom

Tags: html, css

just wanna know why Facebook fixed header don't have a margin or padding bottom but its globalContainer stays exactly after the fixed header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header bar is inside a fixed-height container. Essentially, the code looks something like this (simplified):

```
<div id="blueBarHolder">
    <div id="blueBar">...</div>
</div>
<div id="globalContainer">...</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#blueBarHolder {
    height: 42px;
}
#blueBar {
    position: fixed;
    /* ... */
}
```

The `blueBarHolder` and `globalContainer` elements are both part of the normal document flow. Because `blueBarHolder` is given a fixed height, it takes up space, causing `globalContainer` to appear below it. It's only the `blueBar` element itself that has `fixed` positioning.

If you were to add `display: none` to `blueBar`, the `blueBarHolder` element would still appear on the page, it would just be an empty box. Likewise, if you added `display: none` to `blueBarHolder`, the blue bar would disappear, and so would the gap at the top of the page.